# How to get pages after 10 with Github API v3?

Tags: javascript, github-api

I want to do statistic analysis of a year with Github accounts.

With [Events](http://developer.github.com/v3/activity/events/types/), I can get people's last 30 events (like push and star). API v3 provides paging with at most 10 pages, so I can get the latest 300 events.

But for an active user, 300 events may possibly lie in the same month. So how can I get the events this year (like total push count this year)? I don't have to know the detail of pushes, just the total count will do.

It seems [this site](http://osrc.dfm.io/Ovilia) can do the statistics of this year. But I haven't dive into the code to understand how to do it.

Comment: If the API will give you 300 at most... then you simply don't. I'd contact the Github folks about this. A last resort may be screen scraping, but that's probably a bad idea.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The Events API currently exposes only the last 300 events; there's no way to get around that restriction. Hopefully, the API will provide a longer history of events in the future.

However, you might be interested in the (Unofficial) GitHub Archive project which tracks, stores and exposes events from the public GitHub timeline: http://www.githubarchive.org/. As the [About page for the OSRC project confirms](http://osrc.dfm.io/#how-it-works), they are also using this archive for collecting events.